# How do I test iOS in-App Purchases for an app I want to release globally?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Testing in-App Purchases seems fairly straightforward but I want to release my app globally. If I read the dev guide correctly, it says that I can only have 1 test account per territory. So am I stuck making over 150 test accounts? There has to be a better way!

Comment: The way I see it, you only need to test with one territory anyway. If your side works, Apple's does anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Kheldar. Is there a specific reason that you need to test for all your territories? Personally I would test my app for one territory and assume it works the same for all.

Comment: well i'm just reading the guide, our app certainly can be played globally, but Apple's guide seems to imply that you need to create a user for each territory you're going to have in-App purchases in

Answer (score 0):

They just "suggest" that because it's a good idea to make sure all the currency values are tested for everywhere you want to release it at plus any sort of localization.

Really big companies are the only ones who can truly test that way - it costs a lot of resources to validate every country...

By not doing it you will be fine, plenty of indie apps get released with only enough testing to make sure the app runs with the normal framerate and you can do each of the features without crashing and these apps have done very well in downloads and sells (even with the inevitable 'issue' that pops up here and there). Leave a support e-mail/contact and makes sure to check your reviews for anything major you need to address and you will be good to go.

Just test with your major area or major areas (ie: Your a German living in America and want to make sure your German and America versions are top notch so test the '2' versions and release everywhere!) and handle anything else as/if it comes by.